# Dynamic operators in where clause in Informatica

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is it possible to create dynamic sql operator in Informatica using SQL Transformation. For eg.

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM products p
WHERE p.weight ?operator? '30'
```

where   **?operator?**   can have values: **<, > , =**

or even: **in, not in**

Comment: I tried but I don't know which kind of type should be parameter. For sure not string cause it will be changed with quotations. For instant it will be replace with '<' not simply < so I will get not parsable query.

Comment: Do not use SQL Editor window of SQL Transform to add parameters to the query. Use an expression to build a full query, pass it through an input port and use string substitution (i.e. `~Query_Port~`). It is described well in _SQL Transformation > Query Mode_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Editor window of SQL Transform allows to use **parameter binding** (`?parameter?`) and **string substitution** (`~string~`). You need the latter:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM products p
WHERE p.weight ~operator~ '30'
```

This topic is described well in *SQL Transformation > Query Mode* chapter of the Transformation Guide.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use a parameter for the whole condition, e.g. With this sample paramFile:

```
[s_m_test_source_param]
$$sq_param = Id = 1
```

Use **$$sq_param** value for **Source Filter** property on **Source Qualifier**. In your case youd need to set the $$sq_parameter in this way:

```
$$sq_param = p.weight > '30'
```

Obviously, this is not perfect solution you've been looking for.